# Energy conservation in Landau-Lifshitz Equation

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, quantum-spin, precession

considering the Landau-Lifshitz equation for magnetisation dynamics,

$\frac{\vec{M}}{dt}=-\gamma (\vec{M} \times \vec{H})$

In this article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1005), the author argues that $\vec{M}.\vec{H}$ is constant (just after equation 3).

I tried using a common approach to prove it,
$\frac{d(\vec{M}.\vec{H})}{dt}=\vec{M}.\frac{d\vec{H}}{dt}+\vec{H}.\frac{d\vec{M}}{dt}$
The second term is zero as $\vec{H}$ is perpendicular to the cross product $\vec{M}\times\vec{H}$. But is the first term always zero? If yes, how?

Also, the term $\vec{M}.\vec{H}$ is the potential energy in this case and since there is no damping considered here, it should probably be conserved?

It would be great if someone can give me an intuitive insight into this.

Comment: I think you are correct. You are free to change ${\bf H}$ by an increment parallel to ${\bf M}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H$ has an arbitrary time dependence (exterior imposed field) then you cannot expect $\dot H\cdot M=0$. Therefore you don’t have the conservation of $M\cdot H$ in general.

Note that the equation is trivially true when $H$ is time independent. Thus, in the adiabatic limit, i.e. if the time acale of the variation of $H$ is large compared to the precession of $M$, then the quantity is approximately conserved.

In general though, it is false. You can check the exactly solvable case with $H$ precessing at angular velocity $\omega$. In the rotating frame, the new magnetic moment $M’$ precesses under the influence of constant exterior magnetic field: $H’=H+\frac{1}{\gamma}\omega$. In this case, it is rather $M’\cdot H’\neq M\cdot H$ which is conserved. Indeed, they differ by the term $\frac{1}{\gamma}\omega\cdot M’$ which is not constant. Note that this extra term is periodic, so it is accurate to say that the averaged energy over a period is conserved.

This is a general fact that a periodically varying $H$ will give a constant hamiltonian averaged over a period. However at every instant in time, it will vary in general.

Naturally, all this assumes $H$ to be an imposed external field. If it implicitly depends on $M$ then the result could hold in some cases.

Hope this helps.